# How to fill the text in my edit text?

Tags: android, xml

I have hundreds of lines of text inside my EditText, my edit text's height is set to `match_parent`, however, only a few lines of code is visible making the rest of the screen empty. how do i make the text fill my edit text? [image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/vector"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ed"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="#50dddddd"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lines="5"
    android:maxWidth="5.0dip"
    android:minWidth="10.0dip"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:textColor="#424242"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Write File to Application SandBox"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Read File from Application SandBox"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/antivirus_btn2"
    android:text="  READ  "
    android:textColor="@drawable/antivirus_btn_text2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/antivirus_btn3"
    android:text="  SAVE  "
    android:textColor="@drawable/antivirus_btn_text3" />
```

Comment: Why not a ListView?

Comment: cricket i was able to run gradle projects on eclipse but it doesnt let me run projects, tried 3 plugins already. and now google obsoleted google services and android support library, i'm migrating to android studio, but how do i add support lib and play services lib there?

Comment: Google services nor the support library are deprecated. Just Eclipse ADT. You include both of those as Gradle dependencies. See "Selectively compiling APIs into your executable" at [this link for Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project)

Comment: also, in your code you have `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` on your EditText, it's very different then `fill_parent`

Comment: it was a typo, see the edit

Answer (score 0):

**use LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/vector"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ed"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="#50dddddd"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:textColor="#424242"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1";
    android:text="Write File to Application SandBox"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1";
    android:text="Read File from Application SandBox"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1";
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/antivirus_btn2"
    android:text="  READ  "
    android:textColor="@drawable/antivirus_btn_text2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1";
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/antivirus_btn3"
    android:text="  SAVE  "
    android:textColor="@drawable/antivirus_btn_text3" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely your EditText's height is `wrap_content` and not `match_parent`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/vector"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ed"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

You need to fix it to `match_parent` or `fill_parent`.